# How to handle last fired event on Rx chain

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava for a long time and I thought I know it far enough, but one thing just surprised me.
There is simple code:

```
val disposable = Obervable.fromIterable(1,2,3,4,5)
.map { it + 1 }
.map {
    disposable.dispose()
    it + 2 
}
.doOnNext { it + 3 }
.subscribe { "finish" }
```

So I believed when I call `dispose()` Consumer should stop listening chain, in real Observable stop firing new events, but if event is already in chain it goes to the end and it could be the reason of NPE.

I'm just looking for advice or the best practice to safe handle this case.
In case of Android is it a good option to add `filter { isFragmentAlive }` or just `view != null` before use it?

Comment: I guess you can use switchMap

Comment: In such synchronous chain, you can't get the disposable until the sequence runs to completion as the subscribe call won't return immediately. You need an in-sequence operator such as `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` to stop the setup.